# How to Use Like Query with Between Query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have  a table with field name counselorDate which have value with date and time.But i want to get data between to dates only(not with time).I used following query.But its not worked. please help me

```
  SELECT 
        * 
  FROM poolMainEnqDetails 
       WHERE counselorDate 
       LIKE BETWEEN ('2014-01-01%' AND '2014-01-03%')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of the BETWEEN is flawed, it should be

```
BETWEEN '2014-01-01%' AND '2014-01-03%'
```

Also, what does your sql management tool (PHPMyAdmin, SQL Workbench, etc...) tells you ? If it doesn't work, it should either give an error, either give a result you're not expecting.

Comment: Thanks .I got it what you mean

Answer (score 1):

If you compare a date against a datetime the that will be converted to datetime.
With that in mind you'll get the folowing where clause:

```
 SELECT 
    * 
 FROM poolMainEnqDetails 
 WHERE counselorDate >= '2014-01-01' 
   AND counselorDate < '2014-01-04'
```